# How to better rank based on ratings that takes the number of reviews into account?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, rating

Normally on most websites when items are being ranked based on reviews, they’re simply based on the average rating (out of 5 or 10); however, I believe an item that has an average rating of 4 based on 1200 reviews should be ranked higher than an item rated 4.1 based on 2 reviews.

Is there any better way of ranking based on ratings that take into account the number of reviews accurately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Bayesian method was described on [this website](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers/blob/master/Chapter4_TheGreatestTheoremNeverTold/Ch4_LawOfLargeNumbers_PyMC3.ipynb#Example:-How-to-order-Reddit-submissions) that answers my question.

Comment: Hi, could you at least summarize the method in the answer itself (this is at present a link-only answer, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/link-only-answers/info )